# How to get output from randomly sampled k entries from a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras/tf problem using sub-sampling of values from a tensor. My model is given below:

```
x_input = Input((input_size,))
enc1 = Dense(encoder_size[0], activation='relu')(x_input)
drop = Dropout(keep_prob)(enc1)
enc2 = Dense(encoder_size[1], activation='relu')(drop)
drop = Dropout(keep_prob)(enc2)
mu = Dense(latent_dim, activation='linear', name='encoder_mean')(drop)
encoder = Model(x_input,mu)
```

I want to sample from the input randomly and then get the encoded values of the input. The error I am getting is

`ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the tensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 13)`

which I can understand is because "predict" does not work on placeholder but I am not sure what to pass to get the output for a placeholder.

```
# sample input randomly
sample_num = 500
idxs = tf.range(tf.shape(x_input)[0])
ridxs = tf.random_shuffle(idxs)[:sample_num]
sample_input = tf.gather(x_input, ridxs)
# get sample shape
sample_shape = K.shape(sample_input)
# sample from encoded value
sample_encoded = encoder.predict(sample_input) <----- Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the [`predict`](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict) function documentation, it doesn't expect a placeholder or a tensor node as an expected set of input. You have to pass directly the Numpy array (in your case).

If you wish to perform some special data preprocessing which is not part of your regular model, you have to do it in Numpy and avoid Tensor computations for it.